# Python Giving taken screenshots names depending on i

Tags: python-3.x, image, loops, screenshot, pyautogui

I want to take screenshots of a decided area and save the image depending on i in the loop and then scroll and continue. While the scrolling works, i just end up with 1 saved image on each folder, when i should have 5 for each. Help?

```
import time
import pyautogui
import sys


i = 10
while i >=6:
    pyautogui.moveTo(54,662)
    pyautogui.dragTo(578,662,3, button='left')
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(54,398, 524, 528))
    im.save(r"c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\0\(10-i).png")
    i -=1
    time.sleep(1)
    if i==5:
        pyautogui.moveTo(316,916)
        pyautogui.dragTo(3316,398,3, button='left')
        pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
        i-=1

        while 0<=i <5:
            pyautogui.moveTo(578,662)
            pyautogui.dragTo(54,662,3, button='left')
            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
            im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(54,398, 524, 528))
            im.save(r"c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\1\i.png")
            i -=1
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
im.save(r"c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\1\i.png")
```

should be like

```
im.save(f"c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\1\{i}.png")
```

for string template usage. With r you make an raw string which does not help you. Otherwise use

```
im.save("c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\1\" + str(i) + ".png")
```

which may be more readable for you

Answer (score 0):

One problem is definitely that the "i" in the path strings is not converted to its value.

An alternative to @richiek answer is to use:

```
im.save(r"c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\0\(10-{}).png".format(i))
```

and

```
im.save(r"c:\users\yagci\desktop\istanbul\1\{}.png".format(i))
```